# Dynamic Soql On multiple objects

Tags: dynamic-soql

I want to search on multiple objects using dynamic soql,
below is the query where iam want to search any record from any object using dynamic soql.

```
select id,StageName,name,
  (select id,ProductCode,UnitPrice,Quantity,PricebookEntry.product2id,
          PricebookEntry.product2.ProductCode,product2.name from OpportunityLineItems),
  (select id,Phone,QuoteNumber,Tax,TotalPrice from Quotes) 
from opportunity
```

Comment: Hi Nagaraju, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to enjoy our **[tour]**, and then read more about **[ask]**. I suspect that you may be having an **[X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)**, and so I invite you to **[edit]** your question, put more information in about the goal you're trying to accomplish, and let us guide you to an appropriate solution.

Comment: Why don't you use SOSL. SOSL is made for searching